# Does a wireless AP need a router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Basically, I have a laptop with a webserver. The users are in the same room as the webserver.

Question, does a wireless access point need a router if you are not connecting to the WWW? Can the access point just connect directly to the laptop? Again it is NOT connect to the internet, just used internally.

Comment: No, so long as all network traffic is constrained to the LAN.  
If no host is providing DHCP service, then each host will need to be assigned its own static IP address.  
If no host is providing DNS service, then each host will have to be referenced by IP address rather than hostname.

Comment: @sawdust: agree DHCP, but for DNS other alternatives are mDNS or hosts files. (Or 'yellow pages' aka NIS, but almost nobody remembers how to work that.) And some features of modern HTTP servers, and especially HTTPS servers, are designed for named access and don't work so well using address.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no.   All that an AP does is convert an ethernet signal into a Wireless one.   Either another device (often, but not necessarily a router) will be needed to ensure your WIFI enabled computers "play nice" with the rest of the LAN,  or it will need to be statically configured.

Your question is a bit confusing as it talks about connecting to the "WWW".  You should know that the "WWW" is simply a service - its possible to run "WWW" pages for internal use without connecting to the Internet.

Similarly, the geographic location does not define whether a router is needed, rather its the network location.  In a small office, everyone is often connected directly together just using a (dumb) switch - in which case an AP is all you need to extend the network wirelessly - but in more complex environments a router may be used to control traffic and reduce bottlenecks (and in this scenario it would be common for an AP to be used on its own network so it can be properly secured/partitioned from the rest of the network)

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the difference, you need a fair bit of background on what the wireless access point and router are.

To be clear, wireless router is router has routing function. wireless access point is just a wireless switch that has not routing function. Wireless router works as a gateway and a wireless access point.

The only real advantage to using a router as an AP is the built-in switch ports. If you use an AP, you'll also need a switch so you can connect the AP and PC to the cable coming from the main router.

You would buy an access point if you had an existing network and wanted to add wireless capability. You would plug the access point into an existing router, hub or switch.

And as things progressed wireless routers sold in greater numbers and the prices became more competitive. To the point that now in many instances a wireless router will cost you less than an access point. So there is very little reason any longer to buy an access point as most wireless routers now can function as an access point.

But I think in your situation, you don't need to connect a router to the aireless AP.